# NSImageView setImageScaling notWorkingCorrectly

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm having problems scaling an image in nsimageview correctly.  What happens is when the image is loaded, it doesn't fill up the entire nsimageview.  I used NSScaleToFit and it completely stretched the image.  Since I don't know the dimensions of the photo (it changes, depending on what image is used) I can't set the nsimageview to a size and leave it there.  **What I want to do is fill the entire nsimageview with an image, proportionally, even if some of the image is cut off.**

This is the code that I'm using:

```
NSString *image_path = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:desktop_name];
        NSImage *imageFromBundle = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:image_path];
        [ViewImage setImageScaling:NSScaleProportionally];
        [ViewImage setImage: imageFromBundle];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own solution, since the ones that were built-in didn't work.

```
NSRect frame = [MyWindow frame];

   if (abs(windowHeight-[imageFromBundle size].width) > abs(windowWidth-[imageFromBundle size].height)) {
        frame.size.height = windowWidth;
        frame.size.width = 1+windowWidth*(([imageFromBundle size].width/[imageFromBundle size].height-(10*pow([imageFromBundle size].width, 2))/(pow([imageFromBundle size].height, 2)* windowHeight)));
    } else {
        frame.size.width = windowHeight;
        frame.size.height = ((windowHeight/[imageFromBundle size].width)*[imageFromBundle size].height);
    }

    [MyWindow setFrame: frame
             display: YES
             animate: YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I wanted to have the image to be scaled to fill but keeping the aspect ratio of the original image. Strangely, this is not as simple as it seems, and does not come out of the box with NSImageView. I wanted the NSImageView scale nicely while it resize with superview(s). I made a drop-in NSImageView subclass you can find on github: [KPCScaleToFillNSImageView](https://github.com/onekiloparsec/KPCScaleToFillNSImageView)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think something like this is built-in; you'll likely have to transform the image yourself.

It is relatively straightforward though; you can see an example implementation [here](http://theocacao.com/document.page/498/).

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactely what I want.  However, I don't think that I'm implementing it correctly.  `NSImage *imageFromBundle = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:image_path];
        
         NSImage* thumbnail = [imageFromBundle imageByScalingProportionallyToSize:NSMakeSize(500,350)];
        
  [ViewImage setImage: thumbnail];`

Comment: The image appears, but the imageByScalingProperotionallyToSize doesn't seem to have any effect.  My image view is 350x350px

Comment: Actually, I used good old pen and paper to implement a scaling algorithm and a centering algorithm (because the link's code didn't work :( )